# Show activated items in Navigation Drawer for android versions lower than HoneyComb

Tags: android, android-support-library, navigation-drawer, android-actionbar-compat

Anyone with an idea what I can use to replace `android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"` attribute in navigation drawer for android versions lower than HoneyComb? How do I show selected items in my drawer? I am using android support library v4 and actionbar compat.